# Problems with text gradients and different length text

Tags: css, text, overflow, gradient

I'm having some trouble with a text gradient on my website. It's best to show with an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/QTANr/1/

I'm using a text gradient to create the gradient look:

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #000, #fff 100%);
-webkit-background-clip: text;
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
```

In the example, the first box is displaying as it should, because the text is the right length. The second box has a shorter slab of text, which also shows as it should. The third box however has a lot of text in it, and as such the gradient doesn't get applied to it.

I am making sure that I only load a certain number of characters, but due to unknown placement of paragraphs on articles and also even different font size, I can't predictably get the exact amount of text from each article, so I am grabbing more than I need and hiding the rest with overflow.

I have to use a text gradient instead of a background gradient as the boxes have a transparent background which shows a texture on it, so I can't just gradient the background to white unfortunately.

I have tried moving the text gradient in to the .post div, but then I lose the colour from the text in the author name; it all shows up black.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a better way, but you can use an overlay with the gradient.

```
div.post-info {
    position: relative;
}
.overlay {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, 
                                        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), 
                                        rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 40%, 
                                        rgba(255, 255, 255, 1));
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

And you put the overlay div inside it.

```
        <div class="post-info">
            <div class="overlay"></div>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla accumsan mauris at metus posuere, vitae laoreet dolor sagittis. Nulla rhoncus, metus sit amet sodales scelerisque, ipsum leo egestas metus, in viverra lectus quam et metus. Mauris leo nulla, pharetra vel ultricies suscipit, porttitor non nibh. Integer quis quam tellus. Donec bibendum purus venenatis accumsan sagittis. Phasellus bibendum sem non orci accumsan suscipit non</p>
        </div>
```

### [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QTANr/2/)